# Delegate role to user within same AWS account as mine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am currently learning AWS, and I stumbled upon this scenario where I want to grant access to a service to a user within the same AWS account as mine, using Roles.

So here is the detail of the scenario I am thinking of,

I am currently an admin IAM user 'A'.  There is another IAM user 'B' with no access to EC2 service (infact he has access to nothing in AWS!).

I want this user B to temporarily have read-only access to EC2 instances. So I create a role, and attach a policy 'AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess' to it.

Now, I want 'B' to switch to this role when he logs in, so  that he can view Ec2 instances.

I am aware that this can also be done by creating a group and assigning the policy to that group, and then adding this user 'B' to that group. 
But I want to do this using roles.

I am not sure if this is even possible in AWS (or worse if this scenario itself is valid?), because the documentation only speaks about cross-account role switch.

Can anyone help me understand this, and let me know if this is even possible and what I need to do?

Comment: Why do you not wish to simply assign the permission to the IAM User themselves? Why do you want them to have to assume a role to do this?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: As I mentioned, I am trying to learn AWS and exploring roles. I am aware that this can be easily done by applying the policy directly to a group or the IAM user itself, but I am more interested in understanding roles in detail and how they work.

Comment: Yes, you can do a role switch within the same account. Do you want to do it via the Console, or via API calls? If it is via the console, just choose **Switch Role** and enter the details. If the user is authorized to Assume the Role then it will work. Please let us know which specific step is causing you difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would do it like this rather than either:

1. Applying the role to a group and adding the user to a group
2. Applying the policy directly to a user.

I think you CAN do what you're trying to achieve, but only by giving the user permission to assume a role via a policy, which would mean you would have to give the user permissions via a policy or group anyway (I'm also not sure if this works for roles within the same account) - in this scenario it just makes more sense to apply the policy to the user directly, rather than doing switch roles.

If you really want to go ahead and use switch roles for this, you should be able to modify the guide here to allow you to do so:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: Yes, you are right... I will have to create a policy for the user to assume role and attach it to the user, which I did, but unfortunately it did not help. It is quite surprising that the AWS document mentions that this scenario can be done, but never provides details on how to do it! OR maybe I am expecting way too much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add an IAM user you simply attach the user to the roles trusted entity directly, for an IAM user group it is more complicated.

An additional policy is required to add the IAM user group to the role, as it is otherwise not possible to add IAM user groups to roles. As a result you have 2 policies for each permission to give rather than just 1.

UserGroup → Policy#1 → Role → Policy#2

`Policy#1` is attached to the UserGroup and has a sts:assumeRole permission for the Role

`Role` has a trusted entity for the account it is actually in eg. arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACC_ID:root

`Policy#2` has your actual permissions, and is attached to the role.